# device not detecting issue with Ubislate 7ci

Tags: android

I wants to attach a finger print device to my android tablet so I am using the code below to detect device to my android tablet.

```
UsbManager mDevManager = (UsbManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usb_devs =  mDevManager.getDeviceList();
Log.d(TAG, "OpenDevice() : usb_devs.size() = "+usb_devs.size());
```

This code works fine (`usb_devs.size()` returns 1) on my Samsung `GT-P3100` tablet but `usb_devs.size()` returns 0 on my `ubslate 7ci` tablet. The Android Version of ubslate 7ci is `4.0.4.`
So what is the issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

To enable USB host API support there must be a file named
android.hardware.usb.host.xml into folder /system/etc/permissions and containing the following lines:

```
<permissions>
 <feature name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
</permissions>
```

I don't have this file inside the /system/etc/permissions folder so I just add this file and reboot device.